# Change from /wp-admin/ to something else?

Tags: customization

I have found a couple of plugins which lets me set another URL. For example example.com/login instead of /wp-admin.
But as soon as you go to that adress you are back on /wp-admin.
So it is only like a redirect.

How do I change it so that all the url's change too?

Comment: Unless you really know what you're doing, you will probably break the site by renaming (plugins may require that structure or need to be changed)

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you don't. The "wp-admin" is hardcoded in many places.

Answer (score 0):

At WPMU DEV they suggest the following Apache configuration if you need to rename the admin/login pages for security/customization.

```
# BEGIN Hide login page
RewriteRule ^mylogin$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wp-login.php?key=123&redirect_to=https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wp-admin/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://%{SERVER_NAME}/wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://%{SERVER_NAME}/login
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^key=123
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=lostpassword
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
# END Hide login page
```

Change mylogin to a slug of your choice and 123 to another more secure passphrase.

Credits: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/hide-wordpress-login-page-2/

Comment: And yet... You still can go to yoursite.com/admin/ and it will redirect you to proper login page ;) There is also one big problem with such solution - if anyone would like to do bruteforce attach, it will generate many 404 errors and rendering 404 page is much slower than rendering of login page - so you'll end up with DDoS instead of brute-force ;)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Add constant to wp-config.php

   ```
   define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'secret-folder');
   define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
   ```
2. Add below filter to functions.php

   ```
   add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);
       function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {
       $old  = array( "/(wp-admin)/");
       $admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
       $new  = array($admin_dir);
       return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
   }
   ```
3. Add below line to .htaccess file

   ```
   RewriteRule ^securelogin/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
   ```

Done…!!!

Now your admin URL will be like: `http://www.example.com/securelogin/`

Note: put `"/"` after `securelogin`